# MFC-hosted WPF usercontrol how to close parent window on button press

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc, interop, c++-cli

I'm trying to get a legacy MFC application and a new WPF usercontrol to shut down a dialog window based on a button press in the WPF usercontrol. In essence, I would like some tips on how I can get the `DoModal()` function of MFC return.

For various reasons the dialog is a MFC `CDialog` started via `DoModal`, which hosts a single WPF component and nothing else. This component then has a button which will need to close the `CDialog` after doing some various tasks. This application is an.. exiting.. case of legacy and it's really hard to track control flow and where the actual message pumps driving this thing resides. It's also full of `#defines` that makes everything twice as difficult as it should be. I *think* I have identified the message pump, so I think I can insert something into that to make it close - if I can get to that from the WPF control.

I do not know how to send a windows message out from the usercontrol to the host, or how to get the `HWND` of the host from the usercontrol. I'm sure there is a way to get that, or another better way of communicating?

Is the correct approach to send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the parent `HWND`? Or perhaps I can send a `WM_USER` to the dialog pump and handle the actual closing there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It should work for any WPF element (if it's a Visual), by finding it's containing HWND, tracing up the HWND tree until it finds the root parent, then sending that a WM_CLOSE message.

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

    //I'd double check this constant, just in case
    static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

    private void CloseContainingWindow(Visual visual)
    {
        // Find the containing HWND for the Visual in question
        HwndSource wpfHandle = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        if (wpfHandle == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find Window handle");
        }

        // Trace up the window chain, to find the ultimate parent
        IntPtr hWindow = wpfHandle.Handle;
        while (true)
        {
            IntPtr parentHWindow = GetParent(hWindow);
            if (parentHWindow == (IntPtr)0) break;
            hWindow = parentHWindow;
        }

        // Now send the containing window a close message
        SendMessage(hWindow, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Comment: Looking good. Just going to test it to make sure. If only this project didn't also feature crazy compile times...

Comment: What will receive the `WM_CLOSE`? Is it the main window or the dialog window? It sorta looks like it closes the main window instead of the dialog, which causes this ball of mud to crash on me :)

Comment: I think it would probably just close the dialog window, not the main window. You'd have to test though. 

Unfortunately I haven't rigged this up in a C++/MFC environment, but I tested the above code in Windows Forms hosting WPF and the behaviour was to close the dialog window.

Comment: Actually it closes the entire window main. I limited the loop a bit to just the right number of iterations. It now works. I am as happy as can be, you've made my day!

Comment: OK, glad to be of assistance! I was about to suggest you could examine the title of each HWND using the GetWindowText API as you head up the tree, and see which one matches your dialog title, but it sounds like you've found a method that works.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a close event in the control. Raise the event when the close button is closed.

In your CDialog-derived class, subscribe to the event, then call EngDialog in the event handler.

Comment: This is probably a good idea, but I'm quite lost in how to handle the interop between WPF events and MFC handlers. I'll see if I can give it a try for the other buttons which needs special treatment.

Comment: Ok, I got this working as well! Turns out it was tricky to do this since the `CDialog` isn't a managed class. I ended up writing a wrapper for the event handling to get this working properly - it ended up cool enough to warrant a blog post as well http://binarysculpting.com/2012/02/24/how-to-handle-wpf-events-in-native-mfc-code/

Answer (score 0):

WM_CLOSE should work, but you have to try it.
Another approach is to post a WM_COMMAND message to the parent dialog.
Sending a WM_USER looks too complicated.